# How do I create a shortcode?

Tags: wordpress

How to fix this shortcode?

```
function post_id_shortcode_func () {
Global $post;
return full_real id = "' $post-> ID '";
}
add_shortcode (' post_id_shortcode ', ' post_id_shortcode_func ');
```

Is this in a shortcode without `$post-> ID`

```
<? php
do_shortcode (' [full_real id = "' $post-> ID '"] ');
?>
```

It's basically a shortcode to a shortcode without the php function.

result `[full_real id = "current post id"]`

is a spreadsheet with the change of several currencies

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
// Creating short code
function full_real_func( $atts ){
        $a = shortcode_atts( array(
            'id' => '', //Provide any default id.
        ), $atts );

        return esc_attr($a['id']); //returns id.
    }
    add_shortcode( 'full_real', 'full_real_func' );

//Calling
echo do_shortcode( '[full_real id="' .$post->ID .'"]' );
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: If you have clarification please comment below.
have a happy code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ShowProduct()
{
  $data = "Welcome to wordpress shortcode.";
  return $data;
}

add_shortcode('products', 'ShowProduct');
```

For more examples- [Codex Wordpress](http://www.codexwp.com/issues/how-to-create-shortcode-in-wordpress/)